# IntelliJ IDEA packages location

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, package

I created the default program and just renamed the classes and placed them in other packages. As a result, I ran into an error that I don't understand and don't know how to solve.
*Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.*

If I write the full path to the fxml file, then everything will work. But what needs to be changed to work with the relative path?

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(Window.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
```

[image]

```
src
└── main
    ├── java
    │   └── com
    │       └── example
    │           └── demo
    │               ├── main
    │               │   └── Main.java
    │               └── rendering
    │                   └── Window.java
    │                   
    │                   
    └── resources
        └── com
            └── example
                └── demo
                    └── rendering
                        └── hello-view.fxml
```

**Main.java**

```
package com.example.demo.main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Window;

import java.io.IOException;
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(Window.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320, 240);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

**Window.java**

```
package com.example.demo.rendering;

public class Window {
}
```

**hello-view.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="com.example.demo.rendering.Window">
  <padding>
    <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0"/>
  </padding>
</VBox>
```

**module-info.java**

```
module com.example.demo {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    opens com.example.demo.rendering to javafx.fxml;
    opens com.example.demo.main to javafx.fxml;

    exports com.example.demo.rendering;
    exports com.example.demo.main;
}
```

Comment: The code you posted should work. It's not usually a good idea to name your classes the same as common classes in the libraries you are using, though. Make sure your `Main.java` has `import com.example.demo.rendering.Window;` (and not the JavaFX Window class).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other

Comment: Please show your imports. Without them, your example is incomplete (i.e., not a [mre]).

Comment: I apologize for not showing imports

Comment: After that edit, the problem becomes clear; you're importing `javafx.stage.Window`. That won't work, because your resource is not relative to that class. As @James_D said, make sure to import your own window class: `com.example.demo.rendering.Window`. Better yet, rename your own class (but still make sure to import it).

Comment: yes, it worked. Thank you very much. I am learning java recently, so I didn't notice such a moment.